# How to update url parameters (CQL_FILTER) in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers

I have a vector layer setup with a CQL Filter:

```
vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
                loader: function (extent, resolution, projection) {
                    var url = 'http://server01:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
                        'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&' +
                        'typename=sf:TABLE01&' +
                        'CQL_FILTER=ID=355&' +
                        'outputFormat=text/javascript&' +
                        'format_options=callback:gotFetch';
                // use jsonp: false to prevent jQuery from adding the "callback"
                // parameter to the URL
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    jsonp: false
                });
            }
        });
```

I want to have the user press a button and update the id above to 455 (I want to refresh the layer with latest CQL_FILTER data):

CQL_FILTER=ID=455

And then refresh the layer.  How can I refresh the WFS Layer?

(Also I need a wfs layer because I am setting up markers, I cannot use a WMS layer)

This did not work (gotFetch was not called):

```
var params = {
                CQL_FILTER: 'ID=455'
            };
vectorSource.updateParams(params);
```

Comment: what should i do if I want to filter by intersects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the CQL filter in a variable outside the loader function, and call `vectorSource.clear(true)` after changing the CQL filter.

Something like this:

```js
var cqlFilter = 'ID=355';

var urlTemplate = 'http://server01:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
    'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&' +
    'typename=sf:TABLE01&' +
    'CQL_FILTER={{CQLFILTER}}&' +
    'outputFormat=text/javascript&' +
    'format_options=callback:gotFetch';

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
    var url = urlTemplate.replace('{{CQLFILTER}}', cqlFilter);
    $.ajax({url: url, dataType: 'jsonp', jsonp: false});
  }
});

function changeFilter() {
  cqlFilter = 'ID=455';
  vectorSource.clear(true);
}
```

Comment: @erilem This a nice, clean code. I have one question. How `changeFilter` automatically updates the layer, since the [definition](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#clear) of `clear` states that "Remove(s) all features from the source.". So how new data is loaded and how the layer gets updated, just by `clear`? Thanks